# PDF File is not open for print given error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I am trying to open a PDF file for print but it's given an error `File is not PDF document`.

I have used following JS script:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxURL,         
  data: { order_id: idsss,shipment:1, shipping_method : oshipping_method,delivery_method:favorite},
  /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"*/
}).done(function(data) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);         
  console.log(obj);     
  $('#myaccount').prepend(obj.scriptname);
  if(obj.filenames != "")
  {
    var splitFiles = obj.filenames.split(',');
    $.each(splitFiles, function( index, value ) {javascript:jsWebClientPrint.print('useDefaultPrinter=undefined&printerName=null&filetype=PDF&name='+value);
    });
  }
});
```

I have also tried to add content type `application/json; charset=utf-8`, `dataType: "text"`, `dataType: "html"` and also used

```
xhrFields: {
  responseType : 'blob'
},
```

But still not work.

[image]

Comment: The content being returned from your server is not recognised as a PDF file. If it's coming from a stream then you most likely need to add the correct MIME type headers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , So what can i do for resolve this issue. what should i have to take for this could you please guide me?

Comment: From server side have you set content type and correct MIME type header.

Comment: I have set MIME type but  still same issue.